# problem with the if statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m parsing a json file.the logic goes like this, if there is no data in the variable named boy.it got to enter the if loop and if there is data it got to enter the else part.but the problem is even if the variable boy is empty(which shows  empty in the console) the loop still enters the else part..cud u guys help me out..below is the code..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
NSDictionary *boy=[url objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"the boy value:%@",boy);
if (boy == NULL) 
{
Secondetailview *detailViewController1 = [[Secondetailview alloc] initWithItem:boy];    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController1 animated:YES];
[detailViewController1 release];    
}else
{
    FirstViewDetail *detailViewController = [[FirstViewDetail alloc] initWithItem:boy];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use `if (boy == nil)` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Instead do this:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", boy];
if ([str isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //boy is nil do your stuff
}
```

Comment: mkay...i tried using nil..still not able to enter the if loop...do u no any symbols for dictionary ..

Comment: -1 Not true. `nil` == `NULL` == `0` (roughly on the last one), because Objective-C is just hanging off of C/C++. However, using `nil` is by far more idiomatically correct in Objective-C :-)

Comment: @kingston Ok i think i have the right solution now, check out the updated post!

Comment: @Maxner:dude u nailed it. thanks..de above code worked perfectly good

Comment: Cool, please vote up aswell! And don't forget to `[str release]` release the string after your if statement to avoid a memory leak!

Comment: dude for some reason i was able to give only de tick mark..and not to raise de point

Comment: no i think it worked, it says to upvotes now, good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (boy == NULL)
```

with

```
if ([boy count] == 0)
```

Comment: dude its not possible..to count nsdictionary...its getting crashed

Comment: You have problem with NSDictionary *boy=[url objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; . It do not return Dictionary ..

Comment: k..if dats de case i tried comparing if(url==nil) and getting the same result coz its only the values in the url dat i m assingin in the dictionary

Comment: @kingston: [It is possible to count the items in a NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/count).

Comment: @RaviChokshi,Sidnicious:guys.. thanks for ur effort i was able to make the code work...the above answer made it work

Answer (score -1):

Modify your if condition as below and see if that works.

```
((boy == NULL) || ([boy count] == 0))
```